# A naming convention that works with IntelliSense

Tags: c#

I started naming my class instant variables like this:

```
    Car car;
```

The reason being that I think a car is a perfect description for a variable and I don't need to add additional information.

This worked great for me and I was very happy, but there is one issue that drives me crazy.  It messes with the [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) if I want to do the type it may go for the private variable and vice versa.

I've seen people do:

```
    Car myCar;
```

I'm not crazy about it, but it probably would work.

Any ideas about how to do this better?

I would like to add that this mainly applies to instances of classes created inside of methods.

Comment: Another consideration for not doing `Car car;` is that it would be a problem for case insensitive languages like VB.  Perhaps not something many would consider an issue but a possible issue none the less.

Comment: In visual studio, the intellisense is case sensitive (other IDEs probably have an option for case sensitive), so if you type "C" it would go to "Car", if you type "c" it will go for "car"

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I would point out when seeing such code.

You obviously don't have a **naming convention** for variables. I think such a convention is very useful, especially for distinguishing Properties, member-variables and local variables.

Common Conventions in the .NET ecosystem are:

- `_privateVariable` (Used by Microsoft
  and a lot of designer generated code,
  e.g. linq2sql)
- `m_privateVariable` (Also used by Microsoft, I think TypedDatasets are
  generated using this convention, but I'm not sure.)
- Properties always use `PascalCaseAndNoExtras`
- loacl varaibles are always `camelcaseAndNoExtras`

The second thing is about naming a variable like the class at all. I think it is better not to use the name of the class as a variable name. **A good variable name** should convey the **type** and the **meaning** of a variable in the scope the variable is present.

E.g. if you wanted to display information about a car a customer likes to rent you would rather name your variable `m_CarToRent` instead of `m_Car`.

Comment: Just to clarify.  We do use naming conventions.  The issue I am running into is during the creation of an instance variable inside of a method, which according to microsoft should be camelCase.

I do Car car;  If I do Car carToRent; I still have the same problem with IntelliSense because they both start with the same word.  Are you prefixing instance variables inside of methods?  As opposed to private variables (fields) of the class?

Comment: no, I wouldn't. You could try to find a better name for your variable that doesn't start with car. Otherwise typing the first letters, hitting Ctrl+Space and sepping one down isn't too hard either. But with 'Car car' you would get issues with car beeing always replaced by Car.

Comment: Mel, I write code such as `Car car;` or `OracleParameter oracleParameter;` also.  The only time I've had problems with intellisense is in VS.NET (2003).  VS 2005 and 2008 haven't given me problems.  If you're using one of these later versions, maybe your problems are related to some update or hotfix and not your coding conventions?  Or, maybe reset any addins you may have and see if that works?  devenv switches are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You also can use `this` keyword `this.car`.  It will solve your intellisense issue.
I myself prefer what Daniel suggested to use underscore like `_car`.

Comment: This helps for fields, but not for classes that are created inside of a method

Comment: @Mel - you can't create classes inside a method. you mean objects?

Comment: Yes. That is what I wanted to say.

Comment: Inside a method you'd create a specific Car instance.  Now you can name it.

Answer (score 1):

Some people, like me, use `_Car` for private member variables.

Comment: The convention is _camelCase not _PascalCase

Answer (score 1):

One of the good practices would be:

```
public class Driver
{
 private Car _car;
 public Car Car { get { return _car; } }
 public Driver(Car car)
 {
  _car = car;
 }
}
```

_ would mean, the clients of the class don't see this one, and it's better then 'm_' because it does not add anything to just '_' or 'my', because "my" is already an assumption of the usage.

As a guidance, you can try installing Resharper http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ and you will soon get used to a good naming convention.

Before i tried it, i was always changing my naming convention styles, and could not get rid of the awkward 'this' keyword here and there.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is to use prefixes. I use prefixes such as m, e, v, i, p (MemberVariable, Event, Volatile, Index/Iterator, Pointer), etc which allows me to see these different *usages* of variable grouped nicely in intellisense lists, as well as understand instantly how a variable should be used just from its name. I really don't understand why some people don't do this - it is a long proven approach to speed up coding and make programming easier and less error prone (especially with pointers and pointers to pointers). Over the years I've see a lot of avoidable bugs from programmers on my team who refused to follow these simple conventions.

The second is to differentiate type names and instances better.
Using `Car car`, or even worse, a property: `Car Car {get;set;}` as you rightly point out is rather confusing. It's long been accepted that differentiating names based only on case is a bad thing to do, and having two names that are identical (type, property) is even worse.

But there are approaches that can be applied to avoid this (especially for parameters/locals where you may not be using prefixes):

- Use synonyms: `Vehicle car;`.
- Use general (type) and context-specific (instance) terms `Vehicle licensedVehicle`. This helps your instance code describe not just that something is a car, but what form of car you expect it to be

Lastly, things can get worse as you augment your code in the future. Bear in mind what happens when you build a class hierarchy with vague (effectively "non-scalable") naming:

You start off with names like Vehicle.Type. This seems logical: The type of the vehicle (private, passenger, light-goods, heavy-goods). Then you add derived classes Car, Bus, Truck. For a Bus (Type=passenger) you want to add a "Type" (minibus, coach, double-decker). So now you have base class Vehicle.Type and derived class Bus.Type that mean completely different things. Avoiding use of the generic term "Type" in both cases by calling them (for example) Vehicle.VehicleType and Bus.BusType clarifies things immensely, and eliminates any chance of programmers mixing them up.

(This isn't a great example, as I've based it on the Car naming idea, but hopefully it gets across the general point - good, specific, descriptive naming minimises the confusion that users of your class and maintainers of your code will face in future)

Answer (score 1):

I will typically use "current" in front of the (local) variable, especially if it's in a loop.

```
Car currentCar = new Car();
```

And

```
foreach( var currentCar in CarList ) {
   currentCar.Xxxx();
}
```

I find this helps with readability, but it's completely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is that confusing to VS, but also it borders on being confusing conceptually.  `Car` should be something like `Accord`, `Celica`, or `Mini` and the instance `myCar`, `car1`, etc.  :-)

Comment: I don't understand this post. There seems to be an implicit assumption that he needs subclasses of Car. Where does 'Accord', 'Celica' etc come from? And I don't see how using 'car1' is any conceptually clearer than using simply 'car'.

Comment: It's better naming the instances.

Comment: What if the class really represents a car and not a make of a car?  How would you name it to make the variable names different?

Comment: @featofawhackplanet:  *Humor:  a difficult concept.*

Comment: @wallyk - well I understand it even less if it's supposed to be a joke.

Comment: type_name != car;  type_name == car type.